# Is it possible to execute simple javascript statments from an input field in a document?

Tags: javascript, forms, input, form-submit

In the example below I've attached a function `main` to an input field. the function contains instructions to send an alert with a variable message (whatever the user enters into the field).

```
<form>
<input type="text" onsubmit="main()" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
function main (param) {
 alert(param)
}
//main();
</script>
```

It doesn't work, but I believe that's because I've made some noob error that I'm failing to recognize. The result of a functioning version of this code would be the ability to submit `"hello world"` and produce an alert box stating 'hello world' (without quotes).

But, further than this, I'd like to be able to pass the likes of `main("hello world");` or just `alert('hello world');` to the input field to produce the same result.

The problem I think I'm running into is that the page is refreshed every time I submit. There are a few questions on here with similar problems where people have suggested the use of `onsubmit="main(); return false;"`, but in fact this does **not** seem to work.

Comment: `type="text submit"` isn't valid.

Comment: "pass the likes of main("hello world") to produce the same result"? You'd like to be able to call `main` and have it submit the value you pass?

Comment: `onsubmit="main('Hello World')"`

Comment: "submit" events aren't fired on `<input>` elements. You can catch other exceptions however: "focus", "blur", "change", "paste", etc.

Comment: It might pay to actually explain in clear language what you are really trying to achieve here.

Comment: @spender I'll try. I want to execute javascript instructions, like `alert("string");`, or `console.log("string")` from an input field. The snippet shows step one --pass an argument. After that I explain that my real goal here is to get to step two --pass a statement. Then I attempt to show that I have done some research which has been fruitless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to `eval()` the value of the input.

**Use with caution, has security impact...**

Returning `false` from a handler stops the regular action so you have no redirect after submitting:

```
<form onsubmit="main(); return false;">
<input id="eval-input" type="text" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
function main () {
 eval(document.getElementById('eval-input').value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Trying it now. This has been the most informative answer so far --if it works I'll accept it as answer.

Comment: Hmm, could you add a snippet in your answer, along with an example command showing what I would pass to it to create a simple alert box?

Comment: @Musixauce3000 the above code is fully working if you wrap it in proper `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`. Just tried it with a new html file on my desktop. If I type `alert('hi');` in the textbox, I get the alertbox.

Comment: @Musixauce3000 ah there is 1 error: `onsubmit` is an attribute of `<form>`, not `<input>`.

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery way:**

You create event listener which will be triggered when user click 'submit'.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="text"/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
   $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert( $('#text').val() );
   });
</script>
```

To prevent page reloading - you should use `event.preventDefault();`

**Pure JavaScript:**

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="text"/>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>


<script>
  var button = document.getElementById("submit");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  button.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    alert(text.value);
  },false);
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know how to read that. Is that javascript?

**EDIT** Oh I see -it's titled jQuery. Well can show me with out jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can detect a form submission:

```
<form onsubmit="foo()">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
    function foo(){
        alert("function called");
    }
</script>
```

I however advise you do this (preference), if you desire to manage the form data through a function:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById("myform").onsubmit=function(event){
        alert("function called");
        //manage form submission here, such as AJAX and validation

        event.preventDefault(); //prevents a normal/double submission
        return false; //also prevents normal/double a double submission
    };
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

use `eval()` to execute a string as JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want to do, you can call the function like this, and writing params[0].value you can access the input value:

```js
    function main(params) {
       //dosomething;
      document.write(params[0].value);
        
    }
```

```html
<form onsubmit="main(this)">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: That's really close. But what if I wanted to call the same function `main`, but the result be an alert? This would require the ability to pass the whole `alert('string');` function to the input, and for the browser to execute the contents of the input field without refreshing.

Comment: You can trigger an alert in the function like this: function main(params){alert(params[0].value);}  Do you mean this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
   onchange="main()"
```

onmouseenter, onMouseOver, onmouseleave ...

```
   <input type="text" onmouseenter="main()" />
```